# Write a statement without calling any function?

Tags: python, function

In order to optimize a code in one single line, I am trying to write a determinate statement in my code without calling any function or method. While I was thinking about this I wondered if this is even possible in my case. I was searching some information about this but it seems to be very rarely, but in my current work I must be able to keep the code intact except that optimize section.
Hope you could give me a hand. Any help is welcome.

This is my current progress.

```
def count_chars(s):
'''(str) -> dict of {str: int}

    Return a dictionary where the keys are the characters in s and the  values
    are how many times those characters appear in s.

    >>> count_chars('abracadabra')
    {'a': 5, 'r': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}
    '''
    d = {}

    for c in s:
        if not (c in d):
            # This is the line it is assumed to be modified without calling function or method
        else:
            d[c] = d[c] + 1

    return d
```

Comment: Bit in the remainder of the code, you *implicitly* call a bunch of methods. For instance the `__iter__` is called in the `for` loop.

Comment: Did you have in mind the ternary operator as in C language ?

Comment: `print({letter : word.count(letter) for letter in set(word)})` or does using .count() violate your rules?

Comment: `d[c] += 1` does key lookup only once, `d[c] = d[c] + 1` does it twice. Here's an improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, as mentioned in the comments, it does implicitly use functions, but I think it may be the sort of thing you are looking for?

```
s='abcab'
chars={}
for char in s:
    if char not in chars:
        chars[char]=0
    chars[char]+=1
```

Result

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}
```